# Red line artefacts on display after PC crash

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

After a seemingly random amount of time my PC sticks with glitch; after reboot, red lines appear on the display. I checked the video card, which shows no visual defects, re-plugged to another PCI and found no difference in the display issue.

How should I trouble shoot this problem?

[image: Picture of a Screen]

Comment: Please don't use dropbox. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: That could be a memory corruption issue, either memory on the graphics card or system memory, try a different graphics card if you can. or test system memory using memtest...http://memtest.org/